# The type or namespace name 'Form3' could not be found

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to call `form3` from `form2` in c# but i always get

> "The type or namespace name 'Form3' could not be found "
>    it works when calling it from form1

```
Form3 f1 = new Form3();
f1.Show();
```

Comment: Is Form3 maybe defined in another namespace? Compare your using directives at the top of the files.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: And, as a code review note, naming a variable referring to an instance of a `Form3` as `f1` will confuse you maintenance programmers forever.  Consider a somewhat more rational naming convention.

Comment: form2 to can't see form1 or form3 , when i try to make an instance of the i get a error

Comment: The thing is, we can't see your code, and we aren't that clairvoyant.  Show use the `using` directives at the top of each file, the `namespace` statement, your `class` declaration, and the function in which your are getting the error (i.e., as if the class had only that one function).  But, before you do that, check to make sure that all of your classes are in the same namespace.